# Why don't layouts automatically resize to fit the window in a Xamarin Forms UWP app?

Tags: forms, xamarin, uwp

When a user enlarges a window hosting a xamarin.forms UWP app the layout/page does not resize, and the window controls disappear. If you make the window smaller everything reposition as expected. How do you get this to behave properly? I thought it was supposed to scale automatically.

[image]

Comment: Could you share your xaml code ?

Comment: It can be reproduced from new code easily. I have a project ready on github. https://github.com/seankanderson/XamarinFormsUwpMasterDetailException

Comment: *window controls disappear?* I could not find window disappear with your code sample.

Comment: When you grab the bottom right corner and enlarge the window width, the minimize, maximize, and close controls disappear. As seen in the posted screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded and tested the project you provided on GitHub and it works normally and resizes as expected. I suspect the problem in your case may be that the UI thread was frozen or you Visual Studio Debugger froze the app. I would suggest restarting your PC and then doing Clean solution from Visual Studio and rebuild again. After these steps it should work normally. If not, perform repair of Visual Studio.

Comment: All I had to do was restart my PC, which I do not do very often.  No idea what was wrong but VS 2017 15.9 was not throwing any errors or failing in any other way.